# Physical location of Service Pricipals in Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, service-principal, azure-application-settings

Everytime I go to create a Service Principal in azure, I go through the steps of creating an Application. Which I understand, cool. My application has authentication rights.

When I create an Automation Run As account, it creates a service principal and and stores a certificate. Where is the certificate or whatever other THINGS make this a service principal? I want to find out what subscriptions my service principal has rights to by list in PowerShell, but some app ID doesn't seem like its the right path.

cool I can get the name of the service principal of the app. ONLY shows me how to do this in powershell. WHAT is the SP ?? WHERE is it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service principals are not on the portal, so you can only use other tools to work with them (like powershell you mentioned).

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal

Comment: lol, you are asking about something you do not understand and that page exactly explains it

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, you want to get Azure AD service principal with PowerShell. You can use PowerShell command "[Get-AzureRmADServicePrincipal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/get-azurermadserviceprincipal?view=azurermps-6.6.0)". The script is as below.

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
Get-AzureRmSubscription
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName "<yourSubscriptionName>"
Get-AzureRmADServicePrincipal
```

Besides,in order to access resources that are secured by an Azure AD tenant, the entity that requires access must be represented by a security principal. This is true for both users (user principal) and applications (service principal). For more details, please refer to [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals).

Comment: Can I Login AS the service principal

Comment: Yes you can. The Azure CLI command is that " az login --service-principal -u <app-url> -p <password-or-cert> --tenant <tenant> ". The Powershell command is that " $Credential = Get-Credential
Connect-AzureRmAccount -Credential $Credential -Tenant "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" -ServicePrincipal   " For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/authenticate-azureps?view=azurermps-6.6.0#sign-in-with-a-service-principal.